# String interpolation in Dockerfile LABEL

Tags: docker, datadog

Using a single dockerfile for all environments has been working great, except for now when trying to do this:

```
LABEL "com.datadoghq.ad.apm"='[ \
    { \
        "service": "service-name", \
        "env": "$ENV", \
        "version": "$VERSION" \
    } \
]'
```

The env and version are not being interpolated. (I get the literal '$ENV' and '$VERSION' strings)

Does `LABEL` support string interpolation?
or should I be taking a completely different approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation for `LABEL`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#label) notes:

> Be sure to use double quotes and not single quotes. Particularly when you are using string interpolation (e.g. `LABEL example="foo-$ENV_VAR"`), single quotes will take the string as is without unpacking the variable’s value.

Your example in fact uses single quotes (probably to avoid backslash-escaping the embedded quotes) and so it trips over this case.  You need to use double quotes instead.

```bash
LABEL "com.datadoghq.ad.apm"="[ \
    { \
        \"service\": \"service-name\", \
        \"env\": \"$ENV\", \
        \"version\": \"$VERSION\" \
    } \
]"
```